# How to use GROUP function (MAX) in FUNCTION?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, function, plsql

```
CREATE TABLE cursor_table(
emp_id NUMBER(10) PRIMARY KEY,
emp_name VARCHAR2(30),
emp_salary NUMBER(5)
);

INSERT INTO cursor_table VALUES(101,'addeesh',25000);
INSERT INTO cursor_table VALUES(102,'arunkumar',28000);
INSERT INTO cursor_table VALUES(103,'ashokkumar',35000);
INSERT INTO cursor_table VALUES(104,'durairaj',22000);


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION high_payed_emp
RETURN NUMBER 
IS
    high_payed_emp_id NUMBER(10):=0;
    DECLARE max_emp_salary = MAX(emp_salary);
BEGIN
    SELECT emp_id INTO high_payed_emp_id
    FROM cursor_table
    WHERE emp_salary = max_emp_salary;

    RETURN high_payed_emp_id;
END;
```

I need to create a function that will find the highest paid employee.

Error message:  **Encountered the symbol "DECLARE" when expecting one of the following: begin function pragma procedure subtype type   current cursor delete exists prior**

Comment: What do you want to return if two (or more) employees have the same highest salary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a SQL statement to use your MAX function.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION high_payed_emp
RETURN NUMBER 
IS
    high_payed_emp_id NUMBER(10):=0;
     max_emp_salary NUMBER :=0;
BEGIN
    SELECT MAX(emp_salary) 
      INTO max_emp_salary 
      FROM cursor_table;

    SELECT emp_id INTO high_payed_emp_id
    FROM cursor_table
    WHERE emp_salary = max_emp_salary;

    RETURN high_payed_emp_id;
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check the code below, you had both syntactical and logical errors.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION high_payed_emp
RETURN NUMBER 
IS
    high_payed_emp_id NUMBER(10):=0;
BEGIN
  select emp_id 
    into high_payed_emp_id  
  from (
    select emp_id 
    from cursor_Table
    order by emp_salary desc
  )
  where rownum = 1;

  RETURN high_payed_emp_id;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the subquery to compare max salary, your code should look like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION high_payed_emp
RETURN NUMBER 
IS
    high_payed_emp_id NUMBER(10);
BEGIN
    SELECT emp_id INTO high_payed_emp_id
    FROM cursor_table
    WHERE emp_salary = (Select max(emp_salary) from cursor_table);
    RETURN high_payed_emp_id;
END;
```

Execution:

```
Select high_payed_emp from dual;
```

OUTPUT:

```
HIGH_PAYED_EMP
--------------
           103
```